# Will HASHBYTES('SHA1', ...) produce same result regardless of server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with files and folders. The path can be very long, and of this reason I cant index it. So I want to generate a shorter unique key for each folder based on the path. I am considering to use below to generate key:

```
HASHBYTES('SHA1', path)
```

Will this always produce same value no mater what server its executed on? Its a azure database so server can change at any time.

Comment: If there was, SHA1 would be useless as a hashing algorithm. You *couldn't* verify anything by regenerating the hash and comparing it to the hash. There isn't. Besides, what do you mean `the path can be very long`? Longer than 4000 characters?

Comment: How about `Checksum`? They most of the time give unique value. Exceptions are there sometimes.

Comment: @PrabhatG no it *doesn't*. `Checksum` has a very high collission rate. It's not even suitable for change detection. Google and you'll find quite a lot of examples of phrases that result in the same checksum value

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : I read here: http://geekswithblogs.net/LifeLongTechie/archive/2011/05/20/do-not-use-only-checksum-or-binary_checksum-as-sole-comparison-in-sql-use-hashbytes.aspx 'small chance that checksum wont change' . Please correct me if you have some blog?

Comment: @ThomasSegato Do you need to store the *full* path? What kind of queries do you want to perform? SQL Server has `hierachyid` which accelerates hierarchical queries tremendously. Searching for folder children or parents will be a *lot* faster if you use `hierarchyid`.

Comment: @PrabhatG the very link you posted says *DO NOT use only CHECKSUM*. This isn't a question about *small* changes either. It's about a lot of values, very different to each other that are statistically guaranteed to result in collisions

Comment: Checksum is not useable as it doesnt have that many unique values and you cannot garantee anything. I almost everytime use some kind of SHA type.And normally i dont agree with my friend @PanagiotisKanavos but this time i do!

Comment: @ThomasSegato a hash value would help only for case-sensitive full path matches. Is this what you want to accelerate?

Comment: Thanks everybody. I dont think the path would ever reach more than 4000 characters. But I have allready seen paths longer than 2k. I think I will go for the hash part. If a few had same ID it woulndt be a disaster. I can ensure its always case sensitive. Why I dont use hierchy is a longer story. I started that road, but we had some challenges in the way the application works that eliminated that option.

Comment: @ThomasSegato hierarchyid itself is conceptually a path made of the numeric IDs of the nodes, eg `/1/3/67`. A `hierarchyID` would be *better* than a hash value in this case.  Searching for a specific child when you know the parent would be a lot easier. The only problem is that to search for a full path without iterating you'd have to know the Ids of all intermediate nodes.

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos. The problem is the nature of the application. The user can point out some folders to migrate, but if sub folders are also migrated then they should be skipped. We have some stored procedures that are recursive to do this, and for this purpose it didnt make sense to use hierachyid's. But normally it would have been our preffered approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SHA-1 is a cryptographic hash function whose output depends solely on its input, so the short answer to your question is "yes". If it varies across servers, it's a bug.

However, note that `HASHBYTES` hashes *all of the bytes of its input*. There are many strings you might consider equal that `HASHBYTES` does not.

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', 'Hello')
-- 0xF7FF9E8B7BB2E09B70935A5D785E0CC5D9D0ABF0

SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', 'HELLO')  -- Case matters
-- 0xC65F99F8C5376ADADDDC46D5CBCF5762F9E55EB7

SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', 'Hello ') -- Spaces matter
-- 0x9646BA13A4E8EABECA4F5259BFD7DA41D368A1A6

SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', N'Hello') -- Unicode matters
-- 0xD2EFCBBA102ED3339947E85F4141EB08926E40E9

SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', N'Hellο') -- Small letter omicron, not o
-- 0x004BFE74DBA30800A3A4C271A9B0172B55C6E40E
```

This matters particularly because the SQL Server rules for equality are different: `HASHBYTES(SHA1, 'Hello ') <> HASHBYTES(SHA1, 'Hello')`, but `'Hello ' = 'Hello'` as far as T-SQL is concerned. Whether that's a good or a bad thing depends on your application, but it needs to be taken into account anyway. For building a hash index on a case-insensitive, accent-sensitive string like a Windows path, you may to consider something like `HASHBYTES('SHA1', LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(path))))` to minimize surprises, and compare accordingly.

Comment: I decided to lowercase all letters in the folder path. Just implemented it for 8 million rows, and it seems to work. The folder names can be changed (upper/lower case) by users, so its a good point that it is case sensitive. I update data each day, and need to be able to find the folder by its hashed value. If its the names that is changed it will be a new row as expected.